# JPA 2.0 retrieve entity by business key

Tags: jpa

I know there have been a number of *similar* posts about this, but I couldn't find a clear answer to my problem.

To make it as simple as possible, say I have such an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private Long id;     // PK

  private String name; // business key

  /* getters and setters */

  /* 
     override equals() and hashCode() 
     to use the **name** field 
   */
}
```

So, `id` is the PK and `name` is the business key.
Say that I get a list of names, with possible duplicates, which I want to store. 
If I simply create one object per name, and let JPA make it persistent, my final table will contain duplicate names - Not acceptable.

My question is what you think is the best approach, considering the alternatives I describe here below and (especially welcome) your own.

### Possible solution 1: check the entity manager

Before creating a new person object, check if one with the same person name is already managed.
**Problem:** The entity manager can only be queried by PK. IS there any workaround Idon't know about?

### Possible solution 2: find objects by query

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.name = ...");
List<Person> list = query.getResultList();
```

**Questions:** Should the objects requested be already loaded in the em, will this still fetch from database? If so, I suppose it would still be not very efficient if done very frequently, due to parsing the query?

### Possible solution 3: keep a separate dictionary

This is possible because equals() and hashCode() are overridden to use the field `name`.

```
Map<String,Person> personDict = new HashMap<String,Person>();
for(String n : incomingNames) {
  Person p = personDict.get(n);
  if (p == null) {
    p = new Person();
    p.setName(n);
    em.persist(p);
    personDict.put(n,p);
  }
  // do something with it
}
```

**Problem 1:** Wasting memory for large collections, as this is essentially what the entity manager does (not quite though!)

**Problem 2:** Suppose that I have a more complex schema, and that after the initial writing my application gets closed, started again, and needs to re-load the database. If all tables are loaded explicitly into the em, then I can easily re-populate the dictionaries (one per entity), but if I use lazy fetch and/or cascade read, then it's not so easy.

I started recently with JPA (I use EclipseLink), so perhaps I am missing something fundamental here, because this issue seems to boil down to a very common usage pattern.

Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution which I can think of is pretty simple, use a [Unique Constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html)

```
@Entity
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="name")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;     // PK

    private String name; // business key
}
```

Comment: Won't this simply make my second insert fail? What I want is to get a reference to the object that the entity manager has already. Basically, the same functionality of em.find, but for my business key.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ensure that the field can be used (correctly) as a key is to create a unique constraint on it. You can do this using `@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="name")` or using `@Column(unique = true)`.

Upon trying to insert a duplicate key the EntityManager (actually, the DB) will throw an exception. This scenario is also true for a manually set primary key.

The only way to prevent the exception is to do a select on the key and check if it exists.

Comment: Adding a unique constraint is sure a good thing to do, but doesn't get me what I want to achieve. Is a query really the only way? What puzzles me is that the entity manager has internally some sort of collection of objects (for which I overrode the `equals()` and `hashCode()`), but isn't accessible. My solution number 3 replicates indeed this functionality (which sounds wrong..). I can't believe this is an unknown issue.

Comment: @cornuz Yes a query is the only way, how else are you going to know what's in your DB?

Comment: well, the em knows! (at least about the attached entities)

Comment: @cornuz You can't rely on that, what if you persisted something yesterday and try to persist an entity with the same key today? What about multiple users/threads?

Comment: I admit I'm ignoring concurrency issues for now, but shouldn't I have the exact same issues when using the PK then? When you issue a query, as in my solution 2, is that always fired to the DB? If the em has all the objects in memory already, will it still go to the DB?

Comment: @cornuz A primary key and a unique constraint behave the same, both are unique keys. I don't know if the entitymanager always goes to the DB.